# Use a value on a cell as a Sheet name to work with a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have 2 excel files , on one im using a vlookup to extract data from the other file but my issue is the following:

File 1 : this one has 12 sheets with names like January, February , Marc , etc.
.
File 2 : On this one I have the vlookup that makes reference to File 1

Now, on file 2 I have cell A1 which has as value the word January .

I have this formula on file 2

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,'[Weekly Team Report- Salvador.xlsx]January'!$A$1:$B$3,2,FALSE),"")
```

As you can see is making reference to a sheet called 'January'

I would like to know if there is any way to use the information I have on cell A1 as sheetname i.e. if I change the value on my cell A1 to February , the sheetname on the formula should change to February instead of January

I hope someone can understand me :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is what formula `=INDIRECT()` is for:

```
 =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Indirect("'[Weekly Team Report- Salvador.xlsx]" & A1 & "'!$A$1:$B$3"),2,FALSE),"")
```

Notice that the entire range being referenced is stuck inside of the `indirect()` formula as a string. And then we concatenate the value from `A1` to that string.

Comment: I do not understand why we are concatenating A1 with January , the value  on A1 is already the sheetname I'm looking for it .  I have tried to do the following:  =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Indirect("'[Weekly Team Report- Salvador.xlsx]" &A1&"&'!$A$1:$B$3"),2,FALSE),"") but it does not work

Comment: Apologies. I have removed the word January as that is nonsensical. Try running the formula without Indirect and confirm that it's giving the correct reference `"'[Weekly Team Report- Salvador.xlsx]" & A1 & "'!$A$1:$B$3"`